# ionic + firebase / authWithOAuthPopup

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

im trying to first app for android and ios.i want to make login with twitter.It work is chrome toggle device mode.But ,So I installed on my android phone i cant login. What is problem? Sorry for my bad english ..

```
  $scope.LoginTwitter = function(){

    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("twitter", function(error, authData) {

      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        alert(error);
      } else {
      // console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        UserControlfunc(authData);
        $state.go("home");

        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase does not support popups on Android and iOS. You should try to use $authWithOAuthRedirect instead. Example here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get google/facebook to work also.
Using popup method I've only had success with iOS (iPad Air 2) but am in no way able to get it to work for android (One Plus 2). It does appear to work on Nexus 6 simulator when I do 'ionic run android' but that is all.

```
$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData) {
   $localStorage.uid = authData.uid;
   $localStorage.token = authData.token;

}).catch(function(error) {
 console.log(error);
});
```

I tried $authWithOAuthRedirect, but no success for either of my devices